# ValueError: unsupported format character '!' (0x21) at index 2235

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I wanted to send a designed Email using HTML thru Python.
I pasted my HTML, CSS codes to msg.content, code follows

```
msg.set_content(
            '''<html lang="en" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
            com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
            <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <style>
                    * {
                        box-sizing: border-box;
                    }

                    body {
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
                        color: inherit !important;
                        text-decoration: inherit !important;
                    }

                    #MessageViewBody a {
                        color: inherit;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    p {
                        line-height: inherit
                    }

                    .desktop_hide,
                    .desktop_hide table {
                        mso-hide: all;
                        display: none;
                        max-height: 0px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }

                    @media (max-width:620px) {
                        .desktop_hide table.icons-inner {
                            display: inline-block !important;
                        }

                        .icons-inner {
                            text-align: center;
                        }

                        .icons-inner td {
                            margin: 0 auto;
                        }

                        .fullMobileWidth,
                        .image_block img.big,
                        .row-content {
                            width: 100% !important;
                        }

                        .mobile_hide {
                            display: none;
                        }

                        .stack .column {
                            width: 100%;
                            display: block;
                        }

                        .mobile_hide {
                            min-height: 0;
                            max-height: 0;
                            max-width: 0;
                            overflow: hidden;
                            font-size: 0px;
                        }

                        .desktop_hide,
                        .desktop_hide table {
                            display: table !important;
                            max-height: none !important;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #4f9f21; background-size: auto;" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-size: auto; background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/LptDwSH/blue-glow-3-2.png'); background-position: top center; background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #000000; width: 600px;" width="600">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="image_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:35px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:35px;width:100%;">
            <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/JtmhRLG/icon.png" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 150px; max-width: 100%;" width="150"/></div>
            </td></tr></table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="image_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr><td style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;">
            <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><img class="fullMobileWidth" src="https://d1oco4z2z1fhwp.cloudfront.net/templates/default/4011/top-rounded.png" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 600px; max-width: 100%;" width="600"/></div>
            </td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-2" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #4f9f21;" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; background-position: center top; color: #000000; width: 600px;" width="600">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="image_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr><td style="padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:5px;width:100%;">
            <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><img class="big" src="https://i.ibb.co/C8S6tTm/adminision-bg.jpg" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 560px; max-width: 100%;" width="560"/></div>
            </td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-3" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #4f9f21; background-size: auto;" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; background-size: auto; color: #000000; width: 600px;" width="600">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="heading_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:25px;text-align:center;width:100%;">
            <h1 style="margin: 0; color: #555555; direction: ltr; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 120%; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><strong>Confirmation of your request</strong></h1>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-top:20px;">
            <div style="font-family: sans-serif">
            <div class="txtTinyMce-wrapper" style="font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px; color: #737487; line-height: 1.8; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 28.8px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">This is a auto response of your Request</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 28.8px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Good Day %s</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 28.8px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">              Your request has been forwarded to our clerks and currently on-hold for screening.</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 28.8px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Please make sure that the requirements you submitted will be the same requirements you'll bring in the due date of request.</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 28.8px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">We will send you a confirmation of your request according to the clerks if it's declined or accepted. With the confirmation you'll be receiving a claim stub that will be used to claim you request.</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px;"> </p>
            </div></div></td></tr></table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="heading_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <h3 style="margin: 0; color: #555555; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 200%; text-align: center; direction: ltr; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: normal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><span class="tinyMce-placeholder">This is a auto response, PLEASE DO NOT REPLY</span></h3>
            </td></tr></table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;">
            <div align="center">
            <!--[if mso]><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://udm.edu.ph/udm2/" style="height:52px;width:219px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="8%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#4f9f21"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px"><![endif]--><a href="https://udm.edu.ph/udm2/" style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#ffffff;background-color:#4f9f21;border-radius:4px;width:auto;border-top:1px solid #4f9f21;font-weight:700;border-right:1px solid #4f9f21;border-bottom:1px solid #4f9f21;border-left:1px solid #4f9f21;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;" target="_blank"><span style="padding-left:60px;padding-right:60px;font-size:16px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 32px;">Visit Website</span></span></a>
            <!--[if mso]></center></v:textbox></v:roundrect><![endif]-->
            </div></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-4" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #4f9f21;" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-position: center top; color: #000000; width: 600px;" width="600">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td class="column column-1" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="image_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;">
            <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><img class="fullMobileWidth" src="https://d1oco4z2z1fhwp.cloudfront.net/templates/default/4011/bottom-rounded.png" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 600px; max-width: 100%;" width="600"/></div>
            </td></tr></table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;" width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:30px;">
            <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif">
            <div class="txtTinyMce-wrapper" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1.2;">
            <p style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"><em><span style="font-size:20px;">Public service through quality education</span></em></p>
            </div></div></td></tr></table>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;" width="100%">
            <tr><td style="padding-bottom:35px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
            <div style="font-family: sans-serif">
            <div class="txtTinyMce-wrapper" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1.2;">
            <p style="margin: 0; letter-spacing: 1px; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1px;">Justice Cecilia Munoz-Palma corner Mayor Antonio J. Villegas Street Mehan Gardens, Ermita, Manila, Philippines 1000</p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1px; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px;"> </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1px;">Tel. No.: (+632)5336-6582 / (+632)5336-8956 / (+632)5336-8966 | Fax. No. (+632)336-6554 | www.udm.edu.ph</p>
            <p style="margin: 0; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1px; mso-line-height-alt: 14.399999999999999px;"> </p>
            </div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>'''
        % (first_name), 'html')
```

I'm geting this error "ValueError: unsupported format character '!' (0x21) at index 2235" and sometimes it gaves the same error but with different character

Tried using [premailer](https://pypi.org/project/premailer/) and received another type of error which is "ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0xa) at index 651"

I'm not really sure how to send these css styles and format it to sendable email. Any insights will be be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` format operator treats every % in the string as a format operation.  You have "%" in there many times.  It's silly to use % for this.  Just split the string into two parts: one before the body, one after the body. then just do `prefix + body + suffix`.  Or, maybe, store this canned data in a file and read it in.

Comment: Hmmm, I get your point in % treats all % in the string as format operation. But I'm kinda lost in the splitting part. Can you give a simple example of it?

Comment: All you are doing there is inserting the body in the middle of the string, right after "Good Day".  So, just split the big string right there.  Do `prefix='''<html ... Good Day'''`, and `suffix = '''</span></p>...</html>'''`.

Comment: Damn, you nailed it!,  I did what you stated and made my set_content to this `msg.set_content("%s <b>%s</b> %s" % (prefix, first_name, suffix), 'html')` Thank you so much!